# Is the standard $\mathbb R^4$ the only one with positive sectional curvature?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

Perelman--Cheeger--Gromoll Soul Theorem states that whenever a complete non-compact Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ has positive sectional curvature, it should be diffeomorphic to an Euclidean Space.

On the other hand, we do know that there are some exotic $\mathbb {R}^4$. Can we infer via the proof of the Soul theorem that whenever $\dim M = 4$ the manifold $M$ is indeed diffeomorphic to the ``standard'' $\mathbb{R}^4$? Or if it does not com from this proof specifically, what do we can infer about geometric properties of these exotic Euclidean spaces? None of these should admit a metric of positive sectional curvature?

Comment: I don't really follow what the question in the second paragraph is. Your statement of the Soul Theorem applies to any manifold M with a complete psc metric, in particular M which are homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^4$, and it promises that they are diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^4$. Thus no exotic R4 carries a complete psc metric. If you drop the word "complete", many do: there exist exotic R4's diffeomorphic to open subsets of the standard R4; think of these as open subsets of $S^4$ and give it the (incomplete) spherical metric.

Comment: @mme, yes, it promossies that the manifold is diffeomorphich to some Euclidean space, the point is that we have more than one smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}^4$, so, does the Soul Theorem implies that these $4$-dimensional manifolds are diffeomorphic to the standard $4$-dimensional Euclidean space?

Comment: "Diffeomorphic to Euclidean space" means to $\Bbb R^4$ with the standard smooth structure. If the authors meant to say "with some possibly exotic smooth structure", they would simply say that the manifold is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: @mme, ok! I shall take your comment into account. I was not aware whether Perelman did know or not about the exotic Euclidean spaces, but it certainly can be derived from the proof then. I thank you!

Comment: "It is derived from the proof": well, it is just part of the theorem. Usually one says that it's derived from the proof when it's not explicit in the theorem (which often means that the theorem is not stated in an optimal way).

Comment: That any open positively curved manifold is diffeomorphic to the Euclidean space is corollary 3.4 of Cheeger-Gromoll soul paper. Perelman showed the same under the weaker assumption that there is a single point of positive curvature.